# What is the difference between multiple kernel learning and ensemble learning?

Tags: kernel-trick, ensemble-learning

From Wiki:

> Ensemble methods use multiple learning algorithms to obtain better
> predictive performance than could be obtained from any of the
> constituent learning algorithms
>
> Multiple kernel learning refers to a set of machine learning methods
> that use a predefined set of kernels and learn an optimal linear or
> non-linear combination of kernels as part of the algorithm.

What is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

Multiple kernel learning is restricted to the kernel methods. Ensemble learning can collect together any classification methods -- kernel SVM and Random Forest and logistic regression could all appear in the same ensemble.

Comment: So if I combine lets say 3 predictions of logistic regression by another logistic regression (linear combination of 3 linear kernels) is it then both MKL and ensemble?

Comment: @user2173836 Logistic regression as I understand it is not a kernel method.

Comment: you can use a kernel trick

Answer (score 1):

You can find a useful explanation on that topic in Sun et a. (2003), particularly in Section 3:

It reaches a conclusion that multiple kernel learning (MKL) is a special instance of ensemble learning (EL). For example, EL does not suffer from the limitation of MKL that the classifiers have the sub-kernels of the same size and the same support vector coefficients (for SVMs).

- Sun, Tao, et al. "[Selective multiple kernel learning for classification with ensemble strategy](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0031320313001738)." Pattern Recognition 46.11 (2013): 3081-3090.